# In CLion, how can I set up multiple cpp files for arduino

Tags: arduino-mega

I'm using the Arduino plugin in CLion. I can't seem to figure out how to have multiple cpp files for my classes. I have been putting the code in my .h up until now, but that's going to bite me soon.